# VS2015 Update 2 Git undo dont work

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I update my VisualStudio 2015 to Update 2 and now I can't undo my local changes with project on TFS git repository. When I click to Undo from menu and confirm undo nothing happens. In Source Control output window it says undo was completed successfully. When I open Git CMD and did same think file was undoing and in VisualStudio I see lock flag before file.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: seems like I'm having a similar problem, but no results yet (

Answer (score 17):

I'm fairly certain this is a bug in Visual Studio 2015 (at least Update 2). Fortunately there is an easy workaround: after attempting the undo and seeing the files remain, simply "stage" the files you are trying to undo, and then they should disappear from the list of changes as expected.

Update: I just had a similar issue with 2017 (v15.8.3) where thousands of files were stuck under "Changes" even though they were unmodified. Staging them all fixed the issue and only the truly modified files were staged.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me get rid of the annoying issue.